# Chat Room Name/Subtext not set for Ask Different Chat

Tags: discussion, chat, meta

If you look at all the chat rooms on SE, (notwithstanding the temporary ones between users etc) they pretty much all have a) a witty name, and/or b) some following subtext, e.g. :

The Frying Pan: Sometimes hot, always heavy. (cooking.SE)

Literature: Read any good books lately? (literature.SE)

Many of them have a generic "General discussion for XXX.stackexchange.com" subtext.

Ours is blank.  Can we set one?  Suggestions as answers, most upvotes after a week wins?

Answer (score 3):

For a chat room name, absent a really eloquent play on words ("The iLounge"), I think "Ask Different Chat" is sufficient for now<sup>1</sup>. I admit that I love the originality of other sites' room names, and would love to get there eventually, but I don't think we have it yet.

Per my comment on Daniel's answer, the best subtext is easily "The misfits. The rebels. The troublemakers." or maybe slightly abuse the quote:

"The crazy ones; The misfits, the rebels, the troublemakers."

<sup>1</sup> Unless folks feel like rallying around "Ask Different Magpies" :D!

Answer (score 2):

**Chat Different** (notice the space) as the room name, with the subtext line reading "Here's to the crazy ones"

Because the whole "Think Different" campaign launched with the reflection:

> Here’s to the crazy ones. The misfits. The rebels. The troublemakers.
>   The round pegs in the square holes. The ones who see things
>   differently. They’re not fond of rules. And they have no respect for
>   the status quo. You can quote them, disagree with them, glorify or
>   vilify them. About the only thing you can’t do is ignore them. Because
>   they change things. They invent. They imagine. They heal. They
>   explore. They create. They inspire. They push the human race forward.
>   Maybe they have to be crazy. How else can you stare at an empty canvas
>   and see a work of art? Or sit in silence and hear a song that’s never
>   been written? Or gaze at a red planet and see a laboratory on wheels?
>   We make tools for these kinds of people. While some see them as the
>   crazy ones, we see genius. Because the people who are crazy enough to
>   think they can change the world, are the ones who do.

Comment: Frankly I think "The misfits. The rebels. The troublemakers." by itself is fitting and perfect for our room's sub-text.

Answer (score 2):

For the room name, I personally like "**One more thing...**"

I haven't got a preference for the subtext yet, but I'm resisting up voting the "misfits" ones as I think it's a bit of a relic

Comment: If "the misfits" is a relic, than so is "Ask Different" -- they allude to the same ad campaign.

Comment: I hear that, but conceptually it's still very different in the same way as in the original meaning, and so that still works well.  The rest, less so.  More mainstream than misfit.   It's still fun though, I would identify with being a square peg for example.

Comment: Macs may be mainstream, but as became clear during the town hall, AD culture might well still be round pegs in square holes wrt the rest of SE

Comment: You can say that again.   That's why Ask Different is still such a great name.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I'm not good at naming things.

What came to mind for a name is **[AppleTalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appletalk)**.
I'm not convinced that this is a great option, since it's pretty obscure.
That said, it may be better than nothing (maybe?).

Comment: The history buff in me loves the name, but were you even alive when AppleTalk was in active development? I think OS 8 was the last new version of AppleTalk, but it was a *big* deal on my ][GS back in 1987.

Comment: @Daniel OS 8 is less than a year younger than me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that "Ask Different Chat" is sufficient for the *primary* chat of the site, but feel free to create your own themed chats.